# Removing Noise and Detecting Circle in Spotlight Using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have been trying to detect circles in spotlight images using OpenCV and have a variety of pictures I am working with, generally looking something like these 4 images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Following some image processing (using a threshold, blurring) I have gotten the images to look something like this:
[image]

However, trying to use the HoughCircles function, even after playing around with it for a while seems to not work. Is there something that I am glossing over while using Hough Cicles, or is there a better way to detect the circles than using HoughCircles?

My current code:

```
import cv2 as cv 
import numpy as np 

img = cv.imread('image.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv.medianBlur(img,33)
assert img is not None, "file could not be read, check with os.path.exists()"
image = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY,73,2)
blur = cv.blur(image,(5,5))
circles = cv.HoughCircles(blur,cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=30)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv.circle(circles,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv.circle(circles,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv.imshow('Objects Detected',blur)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: For this particular image, a fixed threshold at around 110 generates [this](https://i.imgur.com/TnZvTVU.png) binary mask.

Comment: The issue with a fixed threshold is that the amount of brightness of the circle varies from picture to picture, so a simple fixed threshold won't work throughout the images I have.

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/issues-detecting-circle-from-spotlight/13423

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use fix threshold value, one of the simplest way is to try possible thresholds and choose the one that looks good.

In following sample code(C++), threshold value are tried in ascending order until the binalization result shape became "enoughly circle".

```cpp
//Circle fitting (Simple Least Square)
void FitCircle( const std::vector<cv::Point> &Ps, cv::Point2f &C, float &r )
{
    cv::Mat A( (int)Ps.size(), 3, CV_32F );
    cv::Mat B( (int)Ps.size(), 1, CV_32F );
    for( int i=0; i<Ps.size(); ++i )
    {
        const auto &P = Ps[i];
        A.at<float>( i,0 ) = (float)P.x;
        A.at<float>( i,1 ) = (float)P.y;
        A.at<float>( i,2 ) = 1.0f;
        B.at<float>( i ) = (float)(P.x*P.x + P.y*P.y);
    }
    cv::Mat X;
    cv::solve( A,B, X, cv::DECOMP_SVD );
    C.x = X.at<float>(0) * 0.5f;
    C.y = X.at<float>(1) * 0.5f;
    r = sqrt( X.at<float>(2) + C.x*C.x + C.y*C.y );
}

int main()
{
    //Load image as gray-scale
    cv::Mat SrcImg = cv::imread( "SpotLight.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if( SrcImg.empty() )return 0;
    cv::imshow( "Src", SrcImg );

    //Decide threshold value range [Min,Max) to try
    int Min=0, Max=255;
    {
        unsigned int Hist[256] = { 0 };
        for( int y=0; y<SrcImg.rows; ++y )
        {
            const unsigned char *p = SrcImg.ptr<unsigned char>(y);
            for( int x=0; x<SrcImg.cols; ++x, ++p )
            {   ++Hist[ *p ];   }
        }
        {//Decide Min
            unsigned int Thresh = cvRound( SrcImg.rows * SrcImg.cols * 0.9 );
            unsigned int Sum = 0;
            while( Sum < Thresh ){  Sum += Hist[Min];   ++Min;  }
        }
        //Decide Max
        while( Hist[Max]==0 ){  --Max;  }
    }
    
    //Try for each threshold
    for( int Thresh=Min; Thresh<Max-1; ++Thresh )
    {
        //Binalize
        cv::Mat Bin;
        cv::threshold( SrcImg, Bin, Thresh, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );

        //Fit circle to largest contour
        //to evaluate how close the binalization result shape is to a circle
        cv::Point2f Center;
        float Radius;
        double FittingErr = 0;
        {
            //Extract Largest Contour
            std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > Conts;
            cv::findContours( Bin, Conts, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
            if( Conts.empty() )continue;
            int iLargestCont = 0;
            double MaxArea = 0;
            for( int i=0; i<Conts.size(); ++i )
            {
                double Area = cv::contourArea( Conts[i] );
                if( Area >= MaxArea ){  MaxArea = Area; iLargestCont = i;   }
            }
            //Fit circle to the Contour and evaluate the fitting result
            FitCircle( Conts[iLargestCont], Center, Radius );
            for( const auto &P : Conts[iLargestCont] )
            {
                double dx = (double)P.x - Center.x;
                double dy = (double)P.y - Center.y;

                double e = fabs( sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) - Radius );
                FittingErr += e;
            }
            FittingErr /= Conts[iLargestCont].size();
        }
        //Check if Contour shape is "enoughly circle"
        if( FittingErr <= 0.5 )
        {   //Show Result
            cv::Mat Show;
            std::cout << "Thresh = " << Thresh << std::endl;
            cv::cvtColor( SrcImg, Show, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR );
            Show.setTo( cv::Scalar(0,0,255), Bin );
            cv::imshow( "Result", Show );
            cv::waitKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //
    std::cout << "(All try Failed)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result of this sample (Note : I used shrinked size image to input) :

- Threshold value = 167
- Binalized Result is represented as Red color part in below.

[image]

Comment: The reason why I used "circle fitting" is because it happened to be implemented.
Other evaluations (e.g. Circularity etc) may be able to be used, I think.

Comment: This is a nice method. You can implement this idea quite efficiently by visiting pixels in order of intensity, starting at the highest value. Each time you go down a level, you adjust the circularity measurement according to the new pixels added to the shape. This way you do don’t visit the full image for each possible threshold. For example DIPlib has that implemented as [dip.PerObjectEllipsoidFitParameters](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/segmentation.html#dip-PerObjectEllipsoidFit-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-PerObjectEllipsoidFitParameters-CL).

Comment: @Cris Luengo : Thank you for your good suggestions about efficiency.
However, in order to improve processing efficiency, it seems necessary to develop an efficient contour data update way that can handle increasing/integrating regions. (And I can't think of it soon)

Comment: The paper referenced in the linked documentation describes a measure that you can update. There is no contour involved. You can accumulate the 2nd order central moments, which describe the best fit ellipse, and you can accumulate the area. The method then compares the area of the best fit ellipse to the area of the object to determine how much like an ellipse the object looks. You can of course do a similar thing for a circle. ---- anyway, you can just call the function in DIPlib, then you don't need to roll your own.

Comment: I see, It makes sense to treat with Moments.
But, I don't have a rigorous mathematical understanding of the relationship between the covariance matrix and the ellipse (learned it a long time ago but forgot...).
So if I really face problem like this, I'll consider using some library. Thank you.

Comment: @fana thank you for your solution, but unfortunately, as I have attached to OP, the circle is not entirely detected in certain instances. Would it be helpful if I provided more images to show the distinct scenarios which I have to detect the spotlight in?

Comment: Only the first sentence in this post corresponds to the "answer".

Code is just a sample, and it does not mean that it will always achieve the purpose.
"What is the proper way to evaluate each threshold" strongly depends on your situation.
So even if you start with this code, you'll need to adjust some values, processes, etc.

Comment: providing more image samples may help a bit for someone to "tune" his sample code to post.
But sorry, I won't do such specific tuning, because it do not change meaning of my "answer".

Comment: For example... in my code, largest contour is extracted and used without any checks. This may not be appropriate in many cases.
If you know "with good threshold value, only spotlight region will be rest (no other things exit for all your input image)", you can use this precondition to check the goodness of threshold value.
e.g. checking "If there is only one region has enough size and others is very small, it seems good. ( : otherwise, inappropriate)" may be conceivable.

Comment: @fana Thanks for the help, I think most of the confusion is coming from me using Python, making it difficult to translate the code over. For some more clarification, I believe some inconsistencies with my pictures make it difficult to detect the circles. For the second example in the OP, there are holes within the light that aren't being considered as part of the spotlight, causing the result, and for other images, the thresholding I am attempting to implement is not practical because there is brighter light which is surrounding the circle which I am trying to detect.